# localeCompare for Natural Sort?

Tags: javascript, file, sorting

I'm developing a comic book reader and I have a few files (images) that the user uploads (File objects) and I'm using their filenames in order to sort them in the correct order.

I tried using `localeCompare` to perform a natural sort on them, but no luck...

The pages should be sorted in this manner:

```
page1
page2
page3
etc.
```

However, with my current code they are sorted like this:

```
page1  <------
page10
page11
page12
page13
page14
page15
page16
page17
page18
page19
page2  <------
page20
etc.
```

Here is the code I'm using in order to sort correctly:

*(`split()` function is used to get image file name)*

```
comicImages.sort((a, b) => {
        let aSplit = a.webkitRelativePath.split('/')
        let bSplit = b.webkitRelativePath.split('/')
        let compareResult = aSplit[2].localeCompare(bSplit[2], {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'})

        return compareResult
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) takes 3 arguments. The `options` object (`{numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'}`) should be the **third** argument not the second.

```
//----------------------------------------v
input.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'}))
```

Live Example:

```js
const input = [    "page1",
    "page10",
    "page11",
    "page12",
    "page13",
    "page14",
    "other1",
    "other10",
    "other11",
    "other12",
    "other13",
    "other14",
    "other15",
    "other16",
    "other17",
    "other18",
    "other19",
    "other2",
    "other20",
    "page15",
    "page16",
    "page17",
    "page18",
    "page19",
    "page2",
    "page20",
];

//----------------------------------------v
input.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'}))

console.log(...input)
```